# Can't change the shortcuts from keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I saw some other people having the same problem but none of them helped me to fix the problem. I want to change the languages (English and Greek) by clicking alt + shift.

I tried doing it by going on settings --> Shortcuts --> Universal Access but as many times as I clicked alt + shift it didn't worked. It works with other buttons, like enter, but not with alt + shift.

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-keyboard/+bug/1444659), but you can set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> shortcut by using terminal:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L', '<Alt>Shift_R', '<Shift>Alt_L', '<Shift>Alt_R']"
```